# What exception to throw when two values I expect to be equal are not equal? (C#)

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I feel like this has to be a duplicate, but I've tried looking around and can't find what I'm looking for.

The example I'm working with starts with parsing an XML document. In this XML document the name of a person is stated in two different locations. Later in a different method, I need to use this person's name. I can use any of these two references to the person's name in the XML document since they are the same, or so I expect. I first want to check that they are indeed the same. If they are not equal for whatever reason, I feel like it would be best to throw an exception. Is there an exception for when two values that one would expect are equal are not in fact equal?

I considered [`ArgumentException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(loband).aspx), but I'm not sure if that's best since it specifies:

> ArgumentException is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one
>   of the passed arguments does not meet the parameter specification of
>   the called method.

This isn't the case here since the arguments are fine, it's just that the value of one of the properties (i.e. the person's name) is not what I expect it to be.

I suppose the first question you might have is why do I want to throw an exception. Maybe it's not the best option, but I feel it should be done considering that the reason the two names do not match is because when the XML document was created one of the name-writes did not do its job correctly, which I'd probably want to know. I'm not experienced with error handling, so it's possible that this doesn't mean an exception should be thrown. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can write your own exception class for that purpose and throw that instead.

Comment: Why are you having a user provide some information twice, if it's essential that it be the same thing in both places?  Just remove the name from one of the locations.

Comment: @Rahul I considered that. I felt like this had to be a common enough occurrence that there would already be one I could use.

Comment: Parsing, document - sounds like `FormatException` to me.

Comment: @Servy The example here is a lot simpler than what I'm actually working with. It's not actually about people's names. I basically want to make sure that certain XML elements have attributes that correctly reference other XML elements. Also I can't change the design of the XML document. Besides, this was just an example. I feel like this is applicable to a lot of instances where you'd expect two values to match.

Comment: Unless you are writing a library or plan on catching the exception than sometimes a basic Exception with a custom message can work. However the important bit for ArgumentException is that it doesn't match your preconditions, those could be as complex as "both names match" if you think it should be. In either case having a Validating method that can be called and return a value to show failure or what failure would avoid needing to catch any such exception.

Comment: @Drew I don't see how other complexities would be relevant.  The point is the same.  Rather than requiring a user to enter the same thing twice, and breaking when its wrong, just don't force them to enter the information the second time, since you apparently already know it.  If you have lots of instances where you force users to enter brittle data and crash when they do it wrong then *that's a problem* and you should really change the design such that they can't make the mistake in the first place.

Comment: @Servy Users do not enter anything twice. I guess a simplified way of putting it is that there is a program that creates the XML document based on information in a database. I'm not sure how this is accessed (if it's to the same database entry or if there are different repositories, etc.), and I don't see how the two values could be different if they are accessing the same database entry, but I thought it'd be nice to check to make sure.

Comment: @Guvante Yeah that's a good point about ArgumentException. I'll look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I first want to check that they are indeed the same. If they are not equal for whatever reason, I feel like it would be best to throw an exception.

You could use [InvalidOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(loband).aspx), since your operation expects the values to be equal. If the values are not equal, your operation is invalid.

You could also define your own exception. You can afterward customize your exception in regards of your situation / objects to compare.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I interpreted that exception as the typical use case they mention: "Typically, it is thrown when the state of an object cannot support the method call." I understand what you mean, but it still seems a bit odd since the operation is still valid even though the two values are not the same, it's just that it returns false. And yeah, I could always define my own exception. It's not even that big of a deal, I was just curious if there's an exception class that already exists :)

Comment: If the operation is not invalid, then the arguments are invalid. It's either the method that is not valid or the arguments (XML, names, etc.). 

In the latter, I would recommend using `ArgumentException` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx)). The exception is broad and can compensate for every field that can be invalid in your XML.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an exception, this should be a [*code contract*](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970): your code couldn't work if input XML has provided name twice. **It's a requirement of your code to work properly**.

Thus, I would create a `List<string>` at the beginning of your method, and I would accumulate found names in the XML. Once you need to use the whole name, I would check the list with a code contract:

```
Contract.Assert(names != null && names.Count > 0);
Contract.Assert(names.Skip(1).All(name => name == names[0]));
```